# Controls inaccessable in class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have created class in asp.net webforms but asp controls(textbox,dropdowns,etc) are not accessible. What would be possible reason of this problem? Even Responce.Redirect("abc.aspx") is also marked red in class;

calling method finely using this piece of code but controls are underlined red in class :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Admin adminOBJ = new Admin();
    adminOBJ.Add_Patients();
}
```

Comment: If you created this class on your own, make sure you have the correct references called in your `using` statements, and that your class extends `System.Web.UI.Page`. On top of this, be sure your webform references the `cs` file.

Comment: I had added System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: the webform referring (CodeFile="AdminAddPatient.aspx.cs") on webpage.

Comment: If you click on something that has a red line under it, push `CTRL` + `.` (period), it could show you the reference needed to access the class. Give that a try, and if something shows, make sure to use it.

Comment: added system.IO but now when I hover mouse over underlined control it show "(control-name) does not exist in current context".

Comment: You need to add the dll reference then. `System.IO` likely isn't what you need since that's for `File` classes. You need `System.Web.UI.WebControls`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

- in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio, change AdminAddPatient.aspx to
  AdminAddPatient_old.aspx;

  - Right-click your Solution/Project and choose "Add new Item" to add a new page and name it AdminAddPatient.aspx;
  - Copy the body items from AdminAddPatient_old.aspx to the body of AdminAddPatient.aspx
  - Then copy the methods from AdminAddPatient_old.aspx.cs to AdminAddPatient.aspx.cs